# How do I safely install a weight bearing fitness equipment system in an apartment?

Tags: ceiling, mounting, studs

I am looking to (semi) permanently install some fitness equipment in my apartment (the [Lifeline Jungle G XT](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004R3VQU4) system if that helps). It requires installing a strap mounts into either two ceiling joist or [wall stud mounts](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005JQIBNS). The device at maximum use will be holding full body weight, around 235 lbs for the heaviest user, dispersed across the two mounts. Ideally this would be installed in the ceiling for maximum usage/space, but I was also considering installing it above a doorway if possible. I am not sure what the joists are like in our ceilings or how to find out. Are either of these locations strong enough to support that much weight? I have a horrible image in my head of performing an exercise, pulling the joist, and my neighbors, through onto me.

If neither of these solutions are suitable, is there a way, without many power tools (basically just an electric hand drill), to build a free-standing structure that could support this weight?

Comment: How many stories is your apartment building? Are we talking a 2-3 stories or a high-rise? Do you know if the exterior walls are concrete block?

Comment: The apartment building is only three stories and I am on the first floor. It was probably built in the late 80's or early 90's.

Comment: Structurally, if the ceiling is going to fall it's going to fall is you do this or not. Moreover, if it wasn't going to fall on you before it is not going to fall on you by doing this; find a joist though or you'll be falling to the floor.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I felt like using SketchUp, but you can easier secure it to the ceiling or wall.

I roughly used the dimensions on the [Impex Marcy SM2805 Suspension Rack](http://www.ironcompany.com/marcy-suspension-rack.aspx)

The drawing is based off of a few 2x6's and only 1 cable support is shown but there should be 4. 
This would run roughly $100:

- 10x 2x6x8 (some cut to length either at home or in store) ~$5.70 each
- 31ft of cable or chain (chain ~1.60/ft)
- Screws

**DO NOT GET PRESSURE TREATED LUMBER**

You should never used pressure treated lumber for indoor uses.